# C# XmlElement: Why does it always return Nulll?

Tags: c#, xml, config, selectnodes

I'm relatively new to C#, and just started using XmlElement and the SingleNode Method. For some reason "customSettings" keeps returning null, although the XML Document is being loaded correctly. I've checked that by loading it as a string. I've tried everything i could imagine so far including the attempt in the comment. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. Here is my XML Doc:

EDIT: works with solution from CodingYoshi, but is there a better way?

EDIT: changed XML and code for NSGaga to resolve read only exception with NameValueCollection in user.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="users_fächer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <users_faecher>
    <add key="user1" value="value1" />
    <add key="user2" value="value2" />
  </users_faecher>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
string dir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Users.config");
string new_fächer = input[1];
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = dir;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

ConfigurationSection myParamsSection = config.GetSection("users_faecher");

string myParamsSectionRawXml = myParamsSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
XmlDocument sectionXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
sectionXmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(myParamsSectionRawXml));
NameValueSectionHandler handler = new NameValueSectionHandler();

NameValueCollection users_fächer = handler.Create(null, null, sectionXmlDoc.DocumentElement) as NameValueCollection;

users_fächer.Set(user, new_fächer);
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
```

Comment: Nikolas could you post a small console project - the `var customSettings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("data/faecher") as NameValueCollection;` should not be returning null, all is correct there. And you shouldn't be loading config files as XML as that's pretty lame:). There is some other issue here, I'm just not sure what else is that you're doing. So strip all the other stuff just config as you have it and that one line

Comment: @NSGaga found the issue with opening the section, but when i try the set-method on the  NameValueCollection it tells me that its read only although its a custom user.config and not a app.config. ive edited the code and xml data for you to see what i got now

Comment: @NSGaga all edited now, you got any clue why its not letting me edit?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first `add` element:

```
doc.ChildNodes[0].NextSibling.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0];
```

This will get you the first `add` element's `value` attribute.

```
doc.ChildNodes[0].NextSibling.ChildNodes[1]
    .ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Comment: while this is working now, which is awesome, do you have any idea how to fix the previous or modify yours to not have to loop through all childs to find the one with the right key attribute?

Comment: Why do you care about looping through to find the target element you need? If you are worried about performance: how often will you be doing this? And is this becoming a bottleneck?